# Quitar /r, /n de un string

Tags: c#, string

Tengo un string con saltos de lineas `"/n"` y necesito limpiar el string para que quede sin ellos.

```
String ejemplo = "Ejemplo/r/n";

String salida = "Ejemplo";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo usando [`String.Replace`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8), de la siguiente forma:

```
 salida = ejemplo.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);
```

De esta manera reemplazas `\r\n` por [`string.Empty`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.empty?view=netframework-4.8), que es lo mismo que poner `""`.